# How to check to see if my variable contains a string

Tags: c#

In my c# program, I'm reading in lines from a text file and want to check to see if the line that I read in contains the string "EHRS" and if it does, I want to put that line into an array and if not, I want to read in the next line. When I run this, I get an error that tells me that an unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred at the line where I use the contains function.

Here's what I have:

```
string[] concArray = new string[numLinesConcYr];

using (var sr = new StreamReader(mydocpath + @"\concYrLines.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numLinesConcYr; i++)
    {
        concYrLine = sr.ReadLine();
        if (concYrLine.Contains("EHRS") == true)
        {
            concArray[i] = concYrLine;
        }
        else
        {
            concYrLine = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation on [StreamReader.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Return Value
>   Type: System.String
>   The next line from the input stream, or **null** if the end of the input stream is reached.

So `null` is expected, you have to implement defense against it.

```
concYrLine = sr.ReadLine();
if (!string.IsNullOrempty(concYrLine) && concYrLine.Contains("EHRS"))
{
}
```

Comment: The thing is though, it's not null. Whenever I just read in all of the lines into the array and print them out, it prints out all of the lines perfectly

Comment: @asdf: clearly your `numLinesConcYr` is bigger than number of lines in file.

Comment: I use a loop to go through my file and count the lines though so they should be the same

Comment: You got a NullReferenceException, so clearly `concYrLine` is null.

Comment: @asdf: to be sure, for sake of test, try to call `File.ReadAllLines()` and check the number of elements in resulting array

Comment: @Rahul: yep, typo. thanks

Comment: you can as well use a null propagation operator to avoid null facing `concYrLine?.Contains("EHRS")`

Comment: whenever I use File.ReadAllLines(), the number of elements is the same and whenever I print out all of the lines none of them are empty

Comment: @asdf: is the count of line read the same you have it in `numLinesConcYr` variable ?

Comment: the count of lines read is the same as I have in the numLines variable

Comment: @asdf: another option would be to debug and see on which iteration of loop result is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Each time you read a line, your line my have no content. performing a `.Contains("")` check on the line you have read is dependent on the variable returned being an instance of a string. Perform a null check on the `concYrLine` proir to the `.Contains()` method. Like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numLinesConcYr; i++)
{
    concYrLine = sr.ReadLine();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(concYrLine) && concYrLine.Contains("EHRS") == true)
    {
        concArray[i] = concYrLine;
    }
    else
    {
        concYrLine = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is though, it's not null. Whenever I just read in all of the lines into the array and print them out, it prints out all of the lines perfectly

Comment: Also, `concYrLine.Contains("EHRS") == true` is verbose, there is no need for the `== true` as the `Contains` method returns a boolean already

Comment: My Assumption is it must be null, as this article which explains why the exception is thrown https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx When you say you "print them out", where are you printing them?